# Diagnose Stored Proc contention

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Our product has a few complex stored procedures which utilize (MSSQL2008r2/2012) CTE's and or temporary tables/ table variables in order calculate menu or cascading permission structures for uses using the system.

We have noticed via SQL profiler that some times procedures can take several orders of magnitude greater to return than normal. And we were wondering the best cause of action in order to collect the information to determine what is blocking/contending. A good example is a stored procedure which takes 222ms to run against the live database if I run it manually in query analyser, and yet we have seen times of 9000ms and 5000ms.

Without getting into specifics on the actual sp's in question, how do you start identifying which resources are being blocked at the time you see a long duration for a query in profiler?

I've seen suggestions of which queries you can run to diagnose current issues, but in this scenario the contention could be occurring whilst we are not present to spot it. So ideally a SQL Profiler trace would seem the ideal starting point? Do I need two separate profiler traces and compare the two when you see a long duration in the duration trace?

Comment: I have previously found good success with [Ignite for SQL Server - Confio](http://www.confio.com/performance/sql-server/ignite)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to tracing, have you considered extended events?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb630282(v=sql.110).aspx

I have had much more success reading the output of extended events than a trace output and there are numerous examples out there to help you create one.

I have personally used this to find blocking:

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/an-xevent-a-day-21-of-31-the-future-tracking-blocking-in-denali/